# Capturing multiple regexp patterns on the same line

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

Here's what I want to do. I have a file with lines delimited in more than one ways, and I want to capture more than one substrings based on patterns from those lines.

So an example line would be something like this:

```
servername.domain:2017 08 07.SomeText1.otherIrrelevantStuff;SomeText2.MoreStuff
^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

In other words I want to capture "servername", "2017 08 07", "SomeText1" and "SomeText2" in each line of my file.

I tried doing it with perl -P and positive lookahead/behind but only the first one works. The results per line should also be printed in a single line (so piping through several grep -oP's isn't acceptable).

How would you do it?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `awk -F '[.:;]' '{print $1,$3,$4,$6}' file`?

Comment: The desired output per line of the file should be something like this:

servername 2017 08 07 SomeText1 SomeText2

Answer (score 0):

In awk, add desired regexps to the `match`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{
    while(match($0,/servername|2017 08 07|SomeText1|SomeText2/)) {
        b=b (b==""?"":OFS)substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    } 
    print b
}' file
servername,2017 08 07,SomeText1,SomeText2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to extract the string ahead of `.` until `:` or `;` is met. If the logic is what you desired, then you may use `grep` with perl to do that,

```
$ s="servername.domain:2017 08 07.SomeText1.otherIrrelevantStuff;SomeText2.MoreStuff"

$ grep -oP '[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+(?=\.)' <<< "$s"
servername
2017 08 07
SomeText1
SomeText2
```

Brief explanation,

- `(?=\.)` : matches words ahead of the dot
- `[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+`: `grep` would print this part, the pattern which matched 0-9, A-Z, a-z, or spaces.

Comment: The problem in this case with grep is it prints output on different lines. The output should be in a single line (per line of the file), so for example:

    servername 2017 08 07 SomeText1 SomeText2

Comment: Maybe pipeline the output to `tr -d '\n'`